# How to shuffle a NodeList

Tags: javascript, arrays, nodelist

Let's say I have a Nodelist:

`list = document.querySelectorAll('div');`

and I want to shuffle it. How would I do this?

The only answer I came across, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973079/javascript-display-nodelist-in-random-order) suggests turning the nodelist into an `array` using

`var arr = [].concat(x);`

Similarly, the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) suggests the following (to turn a NodeList into an `array`):

```
var turnObjToArray = function(obj) {
  return [].map.call(obj, function(element) {
    return element;
  })
};
```

My question is, is there no way to do this without turning a NodeList into an array?

And, which of the above two methods is better?

And, once you have turned a NodeList into an array, does anything change when you operate on certain members of the array? (I.e. does deleting one node from the array delete it from the NodeList)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to change the order of elements in-place this may help you

```
var list = document.querySelector('div'), i;
for (i = list.children.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    list.appendChild(list.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);
}
```

Working [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/sugabipo/4/edit?html,js,output)

Side note: concat() in general is slower

Comment: Whoa. I like this. But what is it doing? It seems like `appendchild` would duplicate the items on the list? Why is the `|` necessary?

Comment: It wouldn't duplicate, check the DOM :) That `|` is a bitwise OR operator. x OR y yields 1 if either x or y is 1.

Comment: I realize this but it still seems like this could return a decimal for an index. I love this, I just want to understand it

Comment: @Startec `Math.random() * i` in this case, returns a decimal for sure, but that's why I use bitwise operator; `0.2523864833638072 | 0 = 0`, `8.545993074774742 | 0 = 8` etc. As I said, this won't duplicate elements, since we are actually replacing them (adding to the end) within the same parent. This may replace (reorder) an element maybe more than one time but it's fine; and as you can see there are (list.length + 1) iterations.

Comment: This doesn't work on a `NodeList`, it just works on a specific element and its children.

Answer (score 1):

A modern alternative might be to use the CSS Grid or Flexbox Order attribute. The advantage to this approach is that it can be undone by simply removing the style.

```
    var Scramble = function(){
        [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll(".myClass") ).filter( function( _e ){
            _e.style.order =  (Math.floor(Math.random() * (10) + 1));
        } );
    }
```

Comment: This is fun. I was just thinking about trying it!

Comment: Why did you choose filter vs. just a forEach?